# Mule: Invoking an Oracle stored procedure which returns a table of custom type

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, mule

I am using Mule CE 3.6.1. I have the following Database connector configuration calling an Oracle stored procedure.

```
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[call get_phone_email(:userId, :tPhoneRecord)]]></db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="userId" type="NUMERIC" value="#[payload]" />
    <db:out-param name="tPhoneRecord" type="ARRAY" />
</db:stored-procedure>
```

Parameter tPhoneRecord is defined as `IS TABLE OF phone_email%ROWTYPE` (i.e. table of records) in the stored procedure. I have tried specifying the parameter type `ARRAY` but get the error:

```
Message    : Invalid argument(s) in call (java.sql.SQLException). Message payload is of type Object[]
Code       : MULE_ERROR--2
```

I have also tried using other out-param types or not specifying a type without success.

Please let me know what out-param type I should use for an Oracle table of records, or if I should do this in Java instead. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below solution for out parameter.

```
<db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@54.175.245.218:1581:xe" user="user" password="4321" >
    </db:oracle-config>
    <db:data-type name="INtypename" id="12"/>
    <!-- VARCHAR id=12  -->
    <db:data-type name="OUTtypename" id="2002"/>
    <!-- STRUCT id=2002  -->
    </db:data-types>
    ...
    <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[CALL storedprocfnc(:INtypename,:OUTtypename);]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="INtypename" value="#[payload]"/>
            <db:out-param name="OUTtypename" />
    </db:stored-procedure>
```